# Как обеспечить безопасность API

Tags: api, безопасность

У меня есть большое количество сервисом и все они общаются с API. Например фронтенд делает запросы и меняет ОЧЕНЬ важные параметры у пользователя. CORS тут не подходит, т.к другие сервисы это не сайты, а игры и им тоже нужно общаться с API. На данный момент использую api_key, но его видно в браузере. Подскажите как быть

Comment: От чего конкретно вы хотите защититься и чем вам не угодил api_key? Пусть его видно в браузере, в чём проблема?

Comment: Там есть путь меняющий баланс пользователя, если будет виден api_key, то зная его можно будет делать запросы на изменение.

Comment: А зачем вы сделали возможность изменения баланса? Его должен менять только сервер и больше никто

Comment: Изменение баланса - это оформление покупки  внутриигровой валютой

Comment: Вот игра и должна только отправить запрос на покупку и больше ничего, а изменение баланса вследствие покупки - это работа сервера, а не игры

Comment: Api это представление кошелька, который всем заправляет: переводами, оплатой и тд, только это всё производиться с виртуальной валютой.

Comment: Ну так в чём проблема-то? Просто уберите возможность изменения баланса и перестаньте переживать за api_key

Comment: А как ограничить доступ, другим людям к сервера. Просто игра может быть не одна до бесконечности, так что желательно, чтобы этим занимался один сервис

Comment: Очевидно через api_key ограничить, в чём проблема?

Comment: Я просто не понимаю, кто тогда будет

Comment: В браузере , если зайти в сеть можно увидеть api_key

Comment: Ну и пусть можно, в чём проблема-то?

Comment: Там так же есть клиент в виде сайта

Comment: Я рад за ваших клиентов, а проблема-то в чём?

Comment: Разве посторонний не сможет просто взять api_key, и уже с ним делать запросы на сервис

Comment: Так вы не давайте api_key посторонним, у каждого пользователя должен быть свой личный api_key, который они получат только после входа в аккаунт

Comment: А ёмаё, понял. Всё спасибо большое

Comment: (а ещё для api_key крайне желательно ограничить его срок годности, чтобы в случае его попадания посторонним его нельзя было эксплуатировать бесконечно)

Comment: гуглим nonce и соль (для ключа) - вопрос решен.